PS5 USB Headphones to standard 3.5mm TRS type plugs
So I’m wondering if there is an existing project that I’ve missed that has solved this problem.
I have a USB headset (PS5/PC) that connects wirelessly via a USB dongle.
I’m hoping to use the Pi or perhaps a simpler MCU to route the microphone signal from the USB audio out through a standard 3.5 plug and all while taking an audio signal in via a standard 3.5mm stereo and get it to the headphones via the USB dongle
Looking to use with a VOX radio but equally this would potentially work to allow PS5 headphones to work with the Xbox One if it was small enough to mount under the controller
Cheers

what use is an answer like no, there is no existing project to you?

please ask about the problem you are trying to solve, not about the existence of projects

Where is the Raspberry Pi question?
